# Show that a set is an open set

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the subset $D=\{(x,y)\mid x\not=0; y>0\} $ is an open set in $R^2$

I think I have to find an r such that for all $\epsilon$>0 there exists $B_\epsilon(x_o)$ st $|(x-x_0)|<r$ but I always have trouble with further application.

Much appreciate for every little help

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** consder $x\neq 0, y>0$. Can you find an $r$ such as

$$
\forall (x', y') \ \ |x-x'|<r \ \ \& \ \ |y-y'|<r \implies x'\neq 0 \ \ \& \ \  y'>0
$$?

Comment: That is precisely where I got stuck, having trouble finding r

Comment: try $r = \min (|x|/2, y/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $(x,y)\in D$ and $0<r<\min(|x|,y)$ then $U_{x,y}=\{(u,v): ||(u,v)-(x,y)||<r\}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ with $$(x,y)\in U_{x,y}\subset D$$